NxP3143 Uboot encrypted image and roots help
I have an encrypted firmware based on 2 files uImage (kernel) and rootfs (filesystem) and I have got the encryption keys from someone who cracked it. However I don’t know where to start so I can mount those somehow and start modifying them. mkimage/dumpimage doesn’t return the header of the uImage however there is a header for the rootfs. I tried decrypting them but got nowhere as I don’t know which part is encrypted. If someone can please help. Thank you
This is the uImage output (dumpimage does not return anything :

This is rootfs from dumpimage:
$ dumpimage -l rootfs  
Image Type:   Freescale IMX Boot Image  
Image Ver:    2 (i.MX53/6/7 compatible)  
Mode:         PLUGIN  
Plugin Data Size:     302835498 Bytes = 295737.79 KiB = 288.81 MiB  
Plugin Code Size:     0 Bytes = 0.00 KiB = 0.00 MiB  
Plugin Load Address:  6c9053ca  
Plugin Entry Point:   3533782f  
U-Boot Data Size:     302835498 Bytes = 295737.79 KiB = 288.81 MiB  
U-Boot Load Address:  6c9053ca  
U-Boot Entry Point:   3533782f  

$ dumpimage -l uImage  
GP Header: Size 9411c123 LoadAddr 7f1c7cb5  


it is unclear  what you want to know ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I have added some more information. I would like to understand with those 2 files, how I can extract the information using the encryption key so I can modify and encrypt them again. I need to understand how to start. Thank you
